# how do I solve a double integral in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am very new to Mathematica, and I am trying to solve the following problem.

1. I have a cubic equation of the form `Z = aZ^3 + bZ^2 + a + b`. The first thing I want to do is to get a function that solves this analytically for Z and chooses the minimal positive root for that, as a function of a and b.

I thought that in order to get the root I could use:

```
Z = Solve[z == az^3 + bz^2 + a + b, z];
```

It seems like I am not quite getting the roots, as I would expect using the general cubic equation solution formula.

1. I want to integrate the minimal positive root of `Z` over `a` and `b` (again, preferably analytically) from 0 to 1 for `a` and for `a` to 1 for `b`.

I tried

```
Y = Integrate[Z, {a, 0, 1}, {b, a, 1}];
```

and that does not seem to give any formula or numerical value, but just returns an integral. (Notice I am not even sure how to pick the minimal positive root, but I am playing around with Mathematica to try to figure it out.)

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Spaces between `a` or `b` and `z` are important. You can get the roots by:

```
sol = z /. Solve[z == a z^3 + b z^2 + a + b, z]
```

However, are you sure this expression has a solution as you expect? For `a=0.5` and `b=0.5`, the only real root is negative.

```
sol /. {a->0.5, b->0.5}
{-2.26953,0.634765-0.691601 I,0.634765+0.691601 I}
```

Comment: thanks! that works. How would I pick from sol, as a function of p and q, the smallest positive root?

Comment: Good question. I've been thinking about it. The long, secure way I can think of is something like `Select[Sort[sol /. {a->0,5, b->0.5}], Element[#, Reals] && # >= 0 &,  1]` that you could put in some function. However, it will return {} if there are no positive roots. I suppose there are better ways, I'm not an expert myself. It won't give you a analytical solution, in any case.

Comment: I tried Min[Select[sol, Positive]], but the select statements ignores anything that has a and b in it, and only looks for positive numbered values. I would like a function of a and b that does that.

Comment: Yes, you can do that only after you have numbers (a and b replaced by a numerica value).

Answer (score 0):

```
sol = z /. Solve[z == a z^3 + b z^2 + a + b, z];
zz[a0_ /; NumericQ[a0], b0_ /; NumericQ[b0]] := 
        Min[Select[ sol /. {a -> a0, b -> b0} , 
                 Element[#, Reals] && # > 0 & ]]
```

This returns -infinty when there are no solutions. As sirintinga noted your example integration limits are not valid..

```
RegionPlot[NumericQ[zz[a, b] ] , {a, -1, .5}, {b, -.5, 1}]
```

[image]

but you can numerically integrate if you have a valid region..

```
NIntegrate[zz[a, b], {a, -.5, -.2}, {b, .8, .9}]  ->> 0.0370076
```

Edit ---

there is a bug above Select in Reals is throwin away real solutions with an infinitesimal complex part.. fix as:..

```
zz[a0_ /; NumericQ[a0], b0_ /; NumericQ[b0]] := 
        Min[Select[ Chop[ sol /. {a -> a0, b -> b0} ], 
                 Element[#, Reals] && # > 0 & ]]
```

Edit2, a cleaner approach if you dont find Chop satisfyting..

```
zz[a0_ /; NumericQ[a0], b0_ /; NumericQ[b0]] := 
     Module[{z, a, b}, 
          Min[z /. Solve[ 
             Reduce[(z > 0 && z == a z^3 + b z^2 + a + b /.
                  { a -> a0, b -> b0}), {z}, Reals]]]]
RegionPlot[NumericQ[zz[a, b] ] , {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[zz[a, b], {a, 0, .5}, {b, 0, .5 - a}]  -> 0.0491321
```